# Meaning of Machine in Compiler Theory

Tags: java, software, machine-code

Can anyone tell me what does "machine" means in Compiler Theory? Does it mean computer in general or operating system? Actually, the problem is I understand the definition of machine language as "the language understand by the computer". But does machine here refers to anything specific other than computer.

I was reading dragon book Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools. In the class professor told that Java is both compiled and interpreted language. I didn't understand the definition so I referred to the book. I still don't get the following paragraph:

> Java language processors combine compilation and interpretation,
>   as shown in Fig. 1.4. A Java source program may first be compiled into
>   an intermediate form called bytecodes. The bytecodes are then interpreted by a virtual machine. A benefit of this arrangement is that bytecodes compiled on one machine can be interpreted on another machine, perhaps across a network.

Comment: "Machine" language is the 0's and 1's that the computer understands. Everything the computer processes whether it be the BIOS, operating system or programs running on it are eventually reduced to machine language.

Comment: Why downvoted? Which protocol did I break? Is there any way to figure out that the person who downvoted can be contacted to know the precise reason. It would be helpful in future.

Comment: I am confused when we talk that something is machine dependent does it mean OS dependent or computer dependent? Please clarify. Machine definition is also not available on wiki. If you find it please let me know.

Comment: "Machine dependent" is a different context than "machine language." Machine can be a clothes washer, an automobile or just about anything mechanical without context.

Comment: You need to provide some context. Examples where the term "machine" is used and you didnt understand it.

Comment: I thought that machine has a universal definition in programming that's why I was more confused. But it depends on the context. Thanks for the clarification. I have also edited the question which I hope also clear the context.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc machine can be more general than that, a room with a bunch of people at desks passing papers amongst themselves can be a "machine"

Comment: @Delsilon "Machine dependent" typically indicates that something is implemented differently among different machines. For instance, the way numbers are stored in memory may be different for micro processors of different brands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine is computer. But, the machine is not necessarily hardware.

Usually the machine is just hardware. If not, we speak of a virtual machine. Then the machine is software. The bottom line is that the machine executes software (a program).

Here it may start to become a little hazy because we have since long had interpreters, which we do not call virtual machines. So what is the difference? A virtual machine is software that executes the kind of software that was traditionally executed by hardware.

Java adds to the confusion because Java as a platform has a history. It started out as what you quote but grew into a compiled language over time, as it gained traction and people demanded better performance.

Comment: It says that bytecode compiled on one machine can be interpreted on another machine. It means to interpret it on different machine we need different Jvm. Isn't it?  We have to write different program for it which does make it machine dependent. So where is the advantage?

Comment: Doubt cleared from the @Erik's answer.

Comment: I'm a little unsure about this "It started out as what you quote but grew into a compiled language over time".  I don't think there was ever a public version of Java that didn't compile to byte-code.  Whether the byte-code is interpreted is a different discussion.  I remember a lot of people *saying* (incorrectly) that Java was an interpreted language back in the day, though.

Comment: @JimmyJames: "I don't think there was ever a public version of Java that didn't compile to byte-code." – The GNU Compiler for Java was a (now defunct) frontend for the GNU Compiler Collection, and it supported every backend that every other language frontend for GCC supports, including each and every native backend.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Noted, but I was responding to the text that suggested that Java 
 (the language) was interpreted in the standard Java platform at some point.

Comment: @JimmyJames I guess I could have been clearer. My point was that the byte code was interpreted in the initial (Sun) incarnation of Java and the compilation of byte code to native machine code was a later development. At least that is what I remember.

Comment: I think it comes down to the ambiguity of the term 'Java'.  Byte-code is a 'machine language' as much as any other.  You are probably correct in that this is what the author meant but as Jörg has correctly noted, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to talk about a language as compiled or interpreted, other than to assume that means how they are typically evaluated.

Comment: @MartinMaat: your memory is correct. Sun's first release was a pure bytecode interpreter. Borland developed the first JIT as an add-on to Sun's VM. Symantec quickly followed suit, which Sun licensed and shipped 1.1.5. Then, Sun bought back the Self developers they had let go only shortly before to get access to their VM technology: they had developed a Smalltalk VM based on the Self VM and soon realized that Java and Smalltalk are essentially the same and modified their Smalltalk VM to execute JVM bytecode, which they called "Hotspot". The rest is history. (BTW, the same guys later did V8.)

Answer (score 4):

@Martin's answer is correct — and allow me to expand on the subject.

> But does machine here refers to anything specific other than computer.

In this context, machine refers to the interface and contract between the execution environment — often hardware itself — and the software that is trying to accomplish some higher level purpose (e.g. a program in Java or C# or other language).

The machine, represented by an [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), offers capabilities of storage, computation, and decision making, embodied in machine code or machine language, which is the language at the interface between the hardware and software.  An ISA specifies all the instructions that the machine is capable of.  These instructions are encoded in binary as numbers and they are interpreted (efficiently) by the hardware.

> In the class professor told that Java is both compiled and interpreted language.

To execute, Java programs undergo two translation phases.

The first phase of translation of a java program is traditionally called compilation, and this compilation phase takes source code and translates it into Java byte code intermediate (class) format.  This format is machine code but for an abstract or theoretical machine called the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) rather than actual hardware (though some have endeavored to make hardware for the byte codes).

The JVM consumes the byte code representation of a program and runs it.  Some will call this interpretation, however, under the covers we will typically find a [Just In Time Compiler (shortened as "JIT")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) that takes the byte code instructions and translates them into true hardware machine code instructions for the actual processor the JVM is running on.  While it is possible to interpret the byte code instructions, it is much more efficient (for loops and repeatedly called procedures) to perform translation of the byte codes into native hardware machine instructions (these translations are reused by the program's continued execution, whereas an interpreter will work to execute the byte codes directly without the reuse benefit of translation).

Java programs, with their intermediate Java byte code format, offer an independence from the hardware as compared with some other compiled languages, like C and C++.  Java could be a purely compiled language like C or C++, however some of its features benefit from the two stage compilation, in particular dynamic class loading and unloading.

C programs typically suffer a few extra instructions when using functions from different DLLs (dynamically loaded libraries) whereas Java programs usually don't (as a result of the second compilation phase that happens dynamically at runtime, it can optimize cross library calls and classes because the late phase JIT has more information).

C++ systems generally bake in so much knowledge of the classes into the compiled program that they don't support (C++) classes crossing DLL boundaries — the whole program is best recompiled if changes are made in even in what might seem to be isolated areas.

---

In Java's JIT system, dynamically loaded code is known to the JVM — the sizes of base classes and subclasses, the locations of methods are all well-known constants at the time of (just in time) code generation.  Whereas for C, locations of methods must be treated as variables since their values are not known until load time (and there is no secondary code generation phase to optimize code sequences).  C++, for efficiency, makes the assumption that sizes of base and subclasses, as well as field offsets are known at compile time and because machine code is generated this way, it this precludes Java-style dynamic class loading (in Java a base class can change size for a bug fix and only the relevant class file needs to be redistributed, not the whole application.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am currently learning C++, so am not aware of the DLL concept. However, everything else makes sense to me.

Comment: This is a much better answer but I think though that the distinction between interpreted and JIT isn't as cut-and-dried as it seems from this answer (the wiki link does provide more nuance.) The main benefit of JIT isn't loading and unloading.  The big benefit of JIT is the ability to apply optimizations at runtime based on empirical data from actual execution. A section of code that was compiled to machine instructions might be rewritten many times based on how it's used. JIT also allows for things like stack allocation even though Java doesn't provide any direct mechanism for that.

Comment: @JimmyJames: In HotSpot in particular, the main benefit of JIT is the ability to *deoptimize*. You can make compiler optimizations *even if you cannot prove that they are correct*, and then simply throw away the code and fall back on interpretation in case your optimizations were wrong. For example, escape analysis is equivalent to solving the halting problem, so you can't know whether values will escape or not, but you can simply stack-allocate values anyway under the assumption that they won't escape, and when they *do*, you just re-allocate on the heap.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That doesn't really make much sense to me.  In order to believe that, we'd have to think that initial optimization is only done to allow for more deoptimizing.  "so you can't know whether values will escape or not", I'm not so sure about that.  I can look at code and point to values that never escape.  There are cases where it's not provable and a more aggressive optimizer can try that which comes back point of deoptimization: to allow for more aggresive optimization i.e. it's part of optimization, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone tell me what does "machine" means in Compiler Theory? Does it mean computer in general or operating system? Actually, the problem is I understand the definition of machine language as "the language understand by the computer". But does machine here refers to anything specific other than computer.

In general, if you want to know what a specific term means in a specific context, or when used by a specific person, then you need to ask that person which used the term to provide a definition.

In Computer Science, like all science, a term means precisely what it is defined to mean, no more, no less.

If I were to give a very broad definition, that applies to all the different usages of the word in different subfields of CS, and all the different contexts, I would say that a machine is "something that can execute something". Now, that *sounds* very vague, and that is because it *is* very vague: the meaning of the term "machine" is very broad and might differ between different subfields of CS.

Just as an example: bot the C and the C++ language specification have as one of their core concepts the *Abstract Machine*. The specification describes how programs are executed by this Abstract Machine. It is the job of the programmer to write their C (or C++) programs against the rules and restrictions of this Abstract Machine. And it is the job of the compiler writer to ensure that operations of this Abstract Machine are correctly translated to operations on whatever concrete machine they are writing a compiler for, and that those operations behave the same.

This machine is not a real computer. It is not even a virtual machine. It is simply a mathematical / logical construct created purely for the purpose of specifying the behavior of the C (or C++) programming language. In fact, contrary to my own definition above, it doesn't *really* "execute something", it's more that it describes what *would* happen, if it *were* to execute something.

Actually, *very* programming language gives rise to an Abstract Machine for that language, even if the specification for that language does not explicitly describe one. (Likewise, every machine gives rise to a language in which programs running on that machine are expressed!)

> Edit: I was reading dragon book Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools. In the class professor told that Java is both compiled and interpreted language.

This is a terrible, terrible statement. It is so bad that it is [Not Even Wrong](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong). It is non-sensical.

There is no such thing as a compiled language or an interpreted language. Compilation and interpretation are traits of a compiler or an interpreter (duh!), not a programming language. Those two terms live on two different layers of abstraction. If English were a typed language, the term "compiled language" would be a Type Error!

Every language can be implemented by a compiler and every language can be implemented by an interpreter. Many languages have multiple implementations, and for many languages, some of those implementations are compilers and some are interpreters. For example, there are interpreters for C and C++, and there are compilers for ECMAScript, PHP, Python, and Ruby. In fact, *all* currently existing mainstream implementations of those four languages have at least one compiler, some even have multiple compilers.

Here's an example: the V8 ECMAScript execution engine developed by Google, which powers both Chrome and Node.js went through several revisions of its internal architecture. The first version was a pure compiler, it compiled ECMAScript directly to native machine code. This was an optimizing compiler that produced reasonably fast code while itself running reasonably fast as well.

The second iteration of V8 still compiled ECMAScript directly to native machine code, but it had two compilers: a fast compiler which produced slow code, and a slow compiler which produced fast code. The first compiler would compile the code quickly so that the application would start up fast; it would also inject profiling instrumentation into the compiled code. The second compiler would use the profiling information gathered while the program was running to then compile the sourcecode again to very highly optimized code.

After that, came an iteration that replaced the first compiler with an interpreter. Now, the code would start up being interpreted and then later compiled.

So: is ECMAScript a compiled language or an interpreted language? It should be obvious now that this term simply doesn't make sense, if the exact same piece of code executed by the exact same execution engine may at the same time both be interpreted and compiled! It should be clear that this has nothing to do with the language but rather with how a particular version of a particular implementation chooses to execute a particular piece of code.

> I didn't understand the definition so I referred to the book. I still don't get the following paragraph:
>
> "Java language processors combine compilation and interpretation,
>   as shown in Fig. 1.4. A Java source program may first be compiled into
>   an intermediate form called bytecodes. The bytecodes are then interpreted by a virtual machine. A benefit of this arrangement is that bytecodes compiled on one machine can be interpreted on another machine, perhaps across a network."

Again, this is a terrible, terrible way to describe it.

It is simply *wrong*. There is nothing in the Java Language Specification that says that Java *must* be compiled to JVM bytecode. And, in fact, there are implementations of Java that do not use JVM bytecode, such as the native compilation mode of (the now no longer maintained) GNU Compiler for Java. Actually, there is nothing in the JLS which says that Java must be compiled at all.

Likewise, there is nothing in the Java Virtual Machine Specification that says that JVM bytecode must be intepreted. In fact, all currently existing mainstream JVM implementations have at least one compiler. Excelsior.JET is a purely ahead-of-time compiled JVM implementation that has no interpreter and no JIT compiler. The early versions of the Maxine Research JVM were purely JIT compiled, they had no interpreter. (Although an interpreter was added later to improve performance.)

For a typical Java implementation, such as Oracle's JDK, the process is roughly as follows: the developer writes the program in Java. She then uses the Oracle `javac` Java compiler to translate the Java sourcecode to JVM bytecode. This JVM bytecode is what gets shipped to the users.

The user uses the Oracle HotSpot JVM to execute the JVM bytecode. The HotSpot JVM has multiple execution components: it starts out by interpreting the bytecode. Also, while interpreting, it collects statistics about the code. Using those statistics, it finds the parts of the code that are executed most often (the so-called "hot spots"). It compiles these hotspots into native machine code using the C1 JIT compiler. If there are very hot hot spots, it will at some point again compile those using the C2 JIT compiler. Also, both the C1 and the C2 JIT compiler are allowed to perform speculative optimizations that cannot be proven correct. If it turns out that one of those optimizations were illegal, the particular code in question gets "de-optimized", which basically means it gets thrown away, and the interpreter takes over again.

So, as you can see, the statement that "the bytecodes are interpreted" is a gross mis-characterization of what is actually happening. They may or may not be interpreted at the very beginning of the execution, depending on the exact JVM used, and they may or may not be interpreted later on, depending on whether they are hot or cold, and whether they get de-optimized or not. The exact same piece of code may flip back and forth between interpreted and compiled multiple times during a single run of the program.

Comment: "There is no such thing as a compiled language or an interpreted language."  Of course you are correct but it's a little pedantic, no?  I mean when someone says something like this, we know what they are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The quote can be confusing because it uses "machine" in two slightly different ways. First it talks about the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) which executes the Java bytecode. In the last sentence it talks about the physical CPU which the JVM runs on. So Jave bytecode can *indirectly* be executed on different CPU's ("machines") because it is executed in a software virtual machine. Of course the JVM itself have to be compiled for different CPU's to make this possible.

A machine is just something which executes low-level code. This can be a physical CPU or a virtual machine implemented in software or even a purely theoretical construct like a Turing Machine. From a theoretical standpoint these are similar, since you can always emulate a physical processor in hardware and vice versa, even if it is impractical.

(An operating system is not typically considered a machine though since it doesn't directly execute code, it just provides some services for the CPU.)

Outside of compiler theory, machine typically just means computer.

Comment: "Outside of compiler theory, machine typically just means computer." Right, I had done computer organization and there I only assumed machine to be computer and it worked fine for me. :)

Comment: "(An operating system is not typically considered a machine though since it doesn't directly execute code, it just provides some services for the CPU.)" – Well, in one of my software engineering courses, the professor defined a virtual machine as something that fully abstracts something that underlies it. According to that definition, all non-leaky APIs would be virtual machines, and an OS certainly counts. Also note that it makes sense to interpret and analyze an OS (or rather its ABI) as a language, and every language gives rise to a machine for that language. So, it's not as clear-cut.

Comment: IMHO you don't need the "low-level" qualifier.  I would simply state that "A machine is just something which executes code".

Comment: @PeterM: I added "low-level" because interpreters of high-level languages are usually not called virtual machines. E.g. Java or Python as a whole could be called a virtual machine by this definition, but only the sub-component which execute the low-level bytecode is called the virtual machine.